# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: extjs

I got error:

```
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined**
```

when trying to add a child component to a container which has accordion layout.

Below is the error stack call:

```
Element.override.setHeight ext-all-dev.js:24941
Ext.define.setAttr ext-all-dev.js:60477
Ext.define.applyPendingAttrs ext-all-dev.js:79673
Ext.define.runner ext-all-dev.js:79546
Ext.define.flushAnimations ext-all-dev.js:81227
Ext.define.runComplete ext-all-dev.js:81865
callOverrideParent ext-all-dev.js:35
Base.implement.callParent ext-all-dev.js:6171
Ext.override.runComplete ext-all-dev.js:64510
Ext.define.run ext-all-dev.js:81842
Ext.define.statics.flushLayouts ext-all-dev.js:64514
Ext.define.statics.resumeLayouts ext-all-dev.js:64521
Ext.resumeLayouts
```

Could you help me find possible reasons? Thanks!

Comment: If you're developing in Chrome try to turn on the "pause on uncaught exceptions" option in the dev tools debugger, then when it does pause, go back in the stack until it makes sense. It's a very helpful method for debugging extJS.
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging#pause-on-uncaught-exceptions

Comment: copy + paste your code snippet. It seems to me you had specified a property but component does not support this property!